# How do use local variables when passing in strings from a text file?

Tags: python, excel, string, loops, xlsxwriter

I'm using xlsxwriter to build an excel sheet. I'd like to have a text file that contains formulas I can iterate through.

Instead of writing the `formula_line` to output.xlsx, I want `formula_line` to pick up `row_as_str` to complete the formula before it is written to output.xlsx as it is taken from the file `formulas.txt`

```
import xlsxwriter

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')
    col = 0
    # Read and loop through formulas.txt
    with open('formulas.txt', 'r') as formula_file:
        for formula_line in formula_file:
            row = 0
            for row in range(1,5):
                row_as_str = str(row)
                worksheet.write(row, col, formula_line)
            col += 1
```

**formulas.txt**

```
"=ROUND(K" + row_as_str + "*M" + row_as_str + ",2)"
"=ROUND(K" + row_as_str + "*N" + row_as_str + ",2)"
"=ROUND(K" + row_as_str + "*O" + row_as_str + ",2)"
"=ROUND(K" + row_as_str + "*P" + row_as_str + ",2)"
"=ROUND(K" + row_as_str + "*Q" + row_as_str + ",2)"
"=ROUND(K" + row_as_str + "*R" + row_as_str + ",2)"
```

It does not need to be a text file.

I FOUND THE SOLUTION

```
import xlsxwriter

with xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'output2.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')
    col = 0

    # Reading from formula file
    counter = 5
    with open('formulas.txt', 'r') as formula_file:
        for formula_line in formula_file:
            row = 0
            for row in range(1, 5):
                row_num_str = str(row)
                row_as_str = ("\" + row_as_str + \"")
                formula = formula_line.replace(row_as_str, row_num_str)
                worksheet.write_formula(row, col, formula)
            col += 1
```

Comment: Somehow it seems to me that you're inventing your own programming language that you store in `formulas.txt`. If you put Python code into the TXT file, why not make it a PY file? Other than that, the evil `eval()` should help.

Comment: The code looks really repetitive to me and violates the DRY principle. Why not iterate over `["M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"]`?

Comment: BTW: doesn't your code write a new formula into the same cell `(row, col, ` always, so one overwrites the other?

Comment: This is an example of the code, there are significantly more complex formulas. I'm not inventing my own language, I'm using Excel's formula language. It isn't python code in `formulas.txt`.

I think I found a solution using `.replace()`

Comment: `+ row_as_str + ` is not Excel, it's Python. You are mixing Excel language and Python language to invent your own Formula language. Inventing programming languages is hard.

Comment: I feel like I can do more with this then. What flaws do you see in the code?